# Refining Query result using SQL Server and Coldfusion

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I have a query which delivers data like

```
ID  Value   AttributeID     IDParent
286 Fleet   9               284         
286 239     10              284         
286 1       12              284         
208 Rivers  9               -1          
208 319     10              -1          
208 0       12              -1
```

This result is need to be refined. Is there a way the using "query of queries"  it can be transformed like

```
ID  Value   PageID     Show IDParent
286 Fleet   239         1    284
208 Rivers  319         0   -1
```

or what will be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
select t.ID,
       t.Value,
       aux1.Value as 'PageID'
       aux2.Value as 'Show'
       t.IDParent
from tablename t
inner join tablename aux1 on aux1.IDParent = t.IDParent and aux1.AttributeID = 10
inner join tablename aux2 on aux2.IDParent = t.IDParent and aux2.AttributeID = 12
where t.AttributeID = 9
```

Comment: I love that... would not of thought of joining itself like that with a numeric test. sweet.

Comment: nice query. rather than ISNUMERIC(t.Value) = 0 in the where clause, I would test for t.AttributeID = 9